# Describe: "Require at least one option" in usage

Tags: bash

What is the proper way to convey the notion of "one or more of the following option flags must be present -a -b -c" in a bash usage message?

(Details on similar problems/solutions, to show my current attempts follow.)

I know how to specify a required argument:

`usage: ./my_script.sh arg_matey.html`

I also know how to specify an optional argument such as `-x`:

`usage: ./my_script.sh [-x] marks_the_spot.py`

I even know how to make mutually exclusive optional arguments:

`usage: ./my_script.sh [-p | -i | -r | -a | -t | -e] walk_the_plank.txt`

But no combination of those seems to satisfy the notion of 1+ option from a list must be used.

Comment: Consider using a multi line usage statement.

`usage: ./my_script.sh flag walk_the_plank.txt
      Flags: [-p | -i | -r | -a | -t | -e]`

Comment: Oh, is that how it is done in the bash/linux land? That would almost be enough right there.  What of allowing multiple arguments that aren't mutually exclusive though. Is that still the syntax?

Comment: Sorry, could't get my comment to show as multi-lined.  Anyway, I'd say yes that would be the paradigm.  Looking at the manages for various commands should give you some guidance.

Comment: Why don't you create an account and post this as an answer? This advice definitely deserves an upvote.

Comment: I don't suppose there is one correct answer, but I might go with `Usage: $0 -p|-i|-r|-a|-t|-e [...]` indicating that one choice needs to be made for the first "argument", but additional "arguments" are accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a multi line usage statement.

```
usage: ./my_script.sh flag walk_the_plank.txt
       Flags: [-p | -i | -r | -a | -t | -e]
```

Comment: I will accept this as the answer if no one else has a better solution over a period of time.